# Django: Filter() not returning anything

Tags: python, django, filter

When I try to use get() it gives me a multiple objects returned error. I tried filter and it returns absolutely nothing. Here is my code:

```
latest_poll_list = Score.objects.filter(user=user.id)
```

It doesn't return anything. Hopefully this is just a syntax error; not an error that I have to re-write the program. Thanks in advance.

get:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/scores/

Django Version: 1.3
Python Version: 2.5.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'es']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/julian/Documents/EpicScore/es/views.py" in scoreindex
  30.     latest_poll_list = Score.objects.get(user=request.user)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in get
  132.         return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  351.                 % (self.model._meta.object_name, num, kwargs))

Exception Type: MultipleObjectsReturned at /scores/
Exception Value: get() returned more than one Score -- it returned 3! Lookup parameters were     {'user': <User: jmeyer>}
```

Comment: Could you post the exact traceback resulting from the `get()` call?

Answer (score 4):

Your `get` call in the traceback is not equivalent to the `filter` call in your question:

```
latest_poll_list = Score.objects.get(user=request.user)
    !=
latest_poll_list = Score.objects.filter(user=user.id)
```

In the first you are passing an object, `user` as the argument, in the second you're passing the id value (probably an integer). Also, without seeing the rest of your code we don't know if `user` and `request.user` are the same.

If you simply exchange `get` for `filter` you should end up with the expected result:

```
latest_poll_list = Score.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

Otherwise you could do:

```
latest_poll_list = Score.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.id)
```

If you pass in the `user` object, the query is internally comparing `user.id` against the database column `user_id` which is how the data for the `ForeignKey` is actually stored.

Answer (score 2):

You have a corrupted dataset, or maybe your models aren't working like you think they are. Somehow you managed to make it so that the user isn't a unique identifier for the Score.

As for why filter isn't returning anything, maybe it's because you're calling it differently?

```
filter(user=user.id)
```

vs.

```
get(user=request.user)
```

This leads me to believe the user is a remote key that gets automagically handled by django, rather than a raw number. Your use of filter is using a raw number, your use of get is using the more idiomatic object-as-relation way.

Comment: It's not corrupt. I want it to return multiple values, so that's why I'm using filter

Answer (score 0):

If the `Score` table has a `user` field which is a ForeignKey to the `User` table, and you have a local variable `user` which is also a `User` object then you should do

```
latest_poll_list = Score.objects.filter(user=user)
```